# Why isn't my overhead door closing completely?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

My garage door doesn't close all the way.
It stays around 15cm open.

[image]

Here is what I did:

1- I adjusted the Opening and closing limits : still the same 15cm open

[image]

2-  I changed the bolt in the connector: that gap increased to 25cm

[image]

3- Changed the connection length in the door: still the same 15cm open

[image]

4- I used lubricant WD-40 in every beam and wheel in the door: no change 15cm open

**Any idea how to make the door close all the way??**

*P.S. it used to close before, but something happened that stopped it from closing all the way*

Comment: WD-40 is not a lubricant. It's a Water Displacer and a very poor excuse for a lubricant. Step zero is "disconnect the opener and see if the door operates correctly by hand."

Comment: @Ecnerwal WD-40 is a brand with multiple products. Some of those are specifically sold with lubricantion as the intended use, e.x. [Gel Lube](https://www.wd40.com/products/spray-gel/), and even the original [Multi-Use Product](https://www.wd40.com/products/handy-can/) is described as a lubricant, even if it's not the primary use: "… displaces moisture and lubricates almost anything".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need two bolts in the arm brackets to hold them together, not just one. That might be what caused the problem, one bolt fell out.

See the picture below, from German garages, to get an idea about what I'm referring to.

[image]

Comment: If replacing the missing bolt doesn't solve the problem, dig out the manual for the opener or find it online and read how to re-program the limits (stops).

Comment: @Llaves  Looking at his picture, I would not recommend moving the limit further since it's already so close to the front of the garage.  Instead he should adjust which holes are used for the bolts in the bar.

Comment: After fixing this issue, be careful -- you might have to undo some of the other adjustments you've made, to prevent the door from overshooting the bottom stop.

Comment: After installing the second bolt, pull the cord to disconnect the drive and operate the door manually. Adjust the stop switches so that are tight against the slider at each end, i.e. to avoid the lift trying to drive the door beyond where it stops. Reconnect the drive and test. You may need to adjust the stop switches slightly, particularly for the door closed position. As previously noted, you may need to change the bolt connections on the arm. It should be at a slight-to-moderate angle toward the drive unit, not vertical, when the door is fully closed.

Comment: Note that the second bolt should be installed at the hole which results in the furthest bolt spread, not just near the other one.